# Антикейлогер с DLL не ставит хук

Tags: c++, c, dll, hook

Код в DLL:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma data_seg(".hdata") // секция в памяти общая для всех процессов
HINSTANCE hi = NULL; // эта переменная может изменяться любым поэтому здесь не должно быть ничего лишнего
#pragma data_seg() // конец секции
#pragma comment(linker, "/section:.hdata,rws") // даем права этой секции
HHOOK hKeyHook = NULL;
DWORD idproc;
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH: // вызывается каждый раз когда новый процесс грузит DLL в свою память
    {
        if (!hi) // запоминаем запустивший хэндл(наша DLL) толко первый раз, чтобы он небыл переписан на новый
            hi = hModule;
        break;
    }
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    {
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK DebugProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) // вызывается при нажатии или отпускании клавиши
{
    if (nCode == HC_ACTION && (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN)) { // нам нужно только нажатие
        printf("Замечен кейлогер");
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hKeyHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);     // обработали передаем дальше
}
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int SetKeyboardHook(void) // эту функцию надо вызывать из приложения для создания ловушек
{
    hKeyHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_DEBUG, &DebugProc, hi, 0);
    return 1;
}
// конец DLL
```

Код программы, вызывающей DLL:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale>
#include <windows.h>

INT main() {
    LPWSTR name = L"dllmain.dll";
    HMODULE namer = LoadLibrary(name);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
    int (*setHook)(void);
    setHook = (int (*)(void))GetProcAddress(namer, "SetKeyboardHook");
    setHook();
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    system("pause");
    ExitProcess(0);
}
```

Хук из DLL почему-то не срабатывает, хотя должен быть. SetHook() возвращает все как надо, ошибок нет. Почему хук не ставится в DLL? Делал всё по примеру(http://uinc.ru/articles/zametki/001.shtml) (естественно, заменяя нужные моменты). Как нужно изменить код, чтобы хук ставился и отлавливал все WH_KEYBOARD(используется WH_DEBUG и структура PDEBUGHOOKINFO?